# Reactjs, inline style with state data

Tags: css, reactjs, inline-styles

I have mapped an array of words to the button group. and in the state I have an index and a color value

```
this.state = {
            selectedWordIndex:'',  //e.g. 3
            selectedWordColor:''  //e.g. rgb(137,197,8)
        }
```

the index and the color are set in another function.

```
var counter = -1;
return this.state.sentenceArray.map((word) => {
        counter += 1
        return (
            <button
                key={counter}
                type="button"
                className="btn btn-default"
                style={{}}>{word}</button>);});
```

how can I change the color of the indexed button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if you want to change the color of button with the index === this.state. selectedWordIndex, following code should work.

```
var counter = -1;
return this.state.sentenceArray.map((word) => {
        counter += 1
        return (
            <button
                key={counter}
                type="button"
                className="btn btn-default"
                style={ this.state.selectedWordIndex === counter ? 
                        { color:this.state.selectedWordColor } : 
                        {}
                      }
            >{word}</button>);});
```